# Membership.ValidateUser(username, password) always return false

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, login-control

I am using Membership Provider with standard Login control.
it was working fine till last week. but now it shows error message such as "**Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.**" Though I didn't show any such message. After debugging i get that Membership.ValidateUser() every time return false. 
1:User is not locked even IsApproved is set properly.
2:In web.config file Application name entry of Membership section is also set properly.
I google this question but mostly saying that Application name should be there in config file, but it's not working with me.

If any one face some kind of issue or is any one know the solution please let me know.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Does it happen in newly sign-up users? What is the password encryption type - Hashed or Encrypted?

Comment: no its happen with existing user. and format is clear but we are using password salt for storing it. i tried it with SHA1 as per one of forum but the result is same.